# Simplest WPF/C# debugging method to check what is going on

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging

With C++/C, the easiest way of debugging is to use cout/printf to print out what is going on to the console.

What would be the equivalent method in WPF/C#?

I thought about using MessageBox(), but WPF doesn't seem to support this function. I also thought about using logging function, but I wonder it's too complicated than printf/cout.

I can use break points in Visual Studio, even so, I need some command to set a break point.

```
if (ABC())
{
    // What command should be here to set a break point?
}
```

Comment: You just click to the left of the code to set a breakpoint.  I should also add MessageBox certainly is supported by WPF.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`Debug.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.write.aspx) and [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) are the methods to use, in a release build (or, more correctly, one where `DEBUG` is not defined) they will be compiled out. To include in builds with `TRACE` defined (eg. debug configuration for both debug and release) then use [`Trace.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.write.aspx) and [`Trace.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline.aspx).

If you have a debugger attached (eg. Visual Studio) then it should show these (in VS its the [Output tool window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs4c1wda.aspx)).

When not running in a debugger a tool like Sysinternal's [Debug View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896647) will show this output.

Comment: Debug.Write and Debug.WriteLine would only print when the solution was set to Debug.  Often times its required to test something in Release mode.  I can speak from personal experience an entire class filled with Debug.WriteLine is ugly.

Comment: Fair point... But not as ugly as a class filled with MessageBox.Show calls that output debug info, and have to be stripped from Release code. ;)

Comment: @Ramhound indeed... I did intent to mention `Trace`.

Comment: @Richard - Equally as ugly.  The solution really is to use breakpoints.  Trace and Debug are only helpful to the developer.  I would agree with perhaps the use of an Assert statement.

Comment: @Ramhound logging (and both Trace and Debug methods feed into this) is key in many applications. While significant (and useful) logging is rare in consumer applications it is key to operating business applications (eg. monitoring that the application is running effectively, and diagnosing when it isn't).

Comment: @Richard - I fully understand they have a use.  My experience has simply been negative.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7821bed5.aspx).

For breaking into debugger, use [System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx). Instead of if() { Break; } construct, please consider [Debug.Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z.aspx) related routines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MessageBox.Show()

Or Debug.Trace

Or make the application type a console app (in project settings) and use Console.WriteLine()

Or use System.Diagnostics tracing

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to cout/printf in C# is Console.WriteLine(String) or Console.Write(String).

Comment: Not so.  It won't do anything when you run the .exe standalone, but the VS host redirects `Console.Out` to the Output window.  While there are better alternatives to using the `Console` methods, Dwight's answer is correct:  those methods are the exact equivalent of cout/printf.

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hello world");

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("hello world");

Debug.WriteLine("hello world");

Debug.Write("hello world");
```

Don't click "Start without debugging button" if you want to see debug logs.

[image]

[image]